# Build association with accepts_nested_attributes using some condition in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have got the following task to do:

There is 2 models: Order and User, and there is form for building a new order. This form must contains fields for building User association - name, phone. I have got no problems with it; I  should just use accept_nested_attributes in Order model and build Order with nested User, it's ok. But if User with the same phone exists already I want just user_id for a new Order be installed as user_id of existed User without creating a new User. How can I do it better? I don't know how to build association using some condition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating a new record for user every single time? Have you tried find_or_create?  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by

Comment: How can I use 'find_or_create' for associated object?

Answer (score 1):

```
@user = User.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number])
```

This way, you only create the user record if it doesn't exist eliminating duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **create action of orders_controller.rb** you could do something like this

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:phone_number])
  if @user
    @order = @user.build_orders(order_params_without_user)
    if @order.save
      redirect_to your_path
    else
      render new
    end
  else
    @order = Order.new(order_params_with_user)
    if @order.save
      redirect_to your_path
    else
      render new
    end
  end
end

private

def order_params_without_user
  params.require(:order).permit(order attributes)
end

def order_params_with_user
  params.require(:order).permit(order_attributes, user_attributes: [ user_attributes ])
end
```

You can simplify it even further by separating the @order.save if-else block in a method and then calling that method inside your create action like:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:phone_number])
  if @user
    @order = @user.build_orders(order_params_without_user)
    order_save(@order)
  else
    @order = Order.new(order_params_with_user)
    order_save(@order)
  end
end

private

def order_params_without_user
  params.require(:order).permit(order attributes)
end

def order_params_with_user
  params.require(:order).permit(order_attributes, user_attributes: [ user_attributes ])
end

def order_save(order)
  if order.save
    redirect_to your_path
  else
    render new
  end
end
```

If you are using rails 4 you can make two private methods **order_params_with_user** and **order_params_without_user**, with **permitting user attributes in order_params_with_user** and then simply pass them on the if-else blocks.

As you mentioned in your comment `how can i use find_or_create`, if you are using rails 4 then you'll have to permit your attributes and you'll pass that to your `find_or_create` method but since you want to permit different attributes in different conditions so it'll be better if you separate them out.

Comment: In this case there are many nested if-else because user or order could not be validated

Comment: @malcoauri what do you mean by `many nested if-else because user or order could not be validated`. Validations are a part of model they will be same in both cases. For an already created user you only needs his/her id to build his/her order which you already have by @user

Comment: Your order creating could be invalid; in this case you should to render 'new' action again

Comment: This code doesn't work properly: if user doesn't exist? When you create a new user but order is invalid then you must remove user before render action again.

Comment: @malcoauri Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55413/discussion-between-user2675613-and-malcoauri).

Comment: @malcoauri if a user doesn't exist i haven't created any user separately. I have only created an order and user is handled automatically by rails `nested_attribute_for`. If any validation error occurs it'll rollback both order and user, just like you were doing it with find_or_create method. For details refer to chat